# Функции и декораторы в Python

Tags: python, функции, декоратор

userbot pyrogram стандартный... взял из примеров из библиотеки... только при определенных условиях нужно запускать внешнюю ф-цию... понимаю, что надо передать внешнюю функцию в ф-цию под декоратором... но ни фига не получается... задолбался... аргументы для внешней ф-ции, естественно, тоже нужно задавать из внутренней по условию... в конечном результате аргументы для внешней ф-ции должны получаться, как переменные, присваиваемые из списка result.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

app = Client("my_account")
result = []

def sum(x, y, z):
    b = x + y + z
    print(b)

sum(2, 3, 4)

@app.on_raw_update()
def raw(client, update, users, chats):
    a = str(update)

    if "types.UpdateNewChannelMessage" in a:
        result.append(a.split()[14])
        result.append(a.split()[19][1:][:-2])
        print(result)

        # sum(2, 3, 4)
        result.clear()
    if "types.UpdateNewMessage" in a:
        result.append(a.split()[14])
        result.append(a.split()[19][1:][:-2])
        print(result)
        result.clear()

app.run()
```

Comment: Напишите текст с картинки текстом. Так всем будет проще.

Comment: ну удалите sum  и не будет запускаться )

Answer (score 1):

Сделал. Все просто. Не знаю, почему раньше не получалось... Видно заклинило уже... Пихал в этот декоратор и так и сяк внешнюю ф-цию, ничего не получалось... Почему-то уверен, что и так пробовал... Но сейчас получилось - удивительно... Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]